# (OPENVPN/OPENSSL) Configuration file routines:STR_COPY:variable has no value:conf_def

Tags: openvpn, openssl, webmin

I can't run "openssl req" to create a new key, the output presents an error

```
error on line 39 of /etc/openvpn/openvpn-ssl.cnf
140264035997600:error:0E065068:configuration file routines:STR_COPY:variable has no value:conf_def.c:584:line 39
```

line 39 of openvpn-ssl.cnf reads:

```
dir             = $dir/keys/    # Where everything is kept
```

Obs.:
I search and found this article, but it is not useful. I don't have a vars file https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2218935

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem solved for me by this:

You need to change script file vars in */etc/openvpn/easy-rsa* and uncomment last line:

```
export KEY_CN="CommonName"
```

Run vars `./vars`
Restart openvpn server.